# SPARK SUBMIT:class not found exception

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark

I have main class **XML.scala**, Project **XMLHDFS**
I am trying to run spark submit job with command 
spark-submit --class com.abc.Import.XMLHDFS.XML /some-path/XMLHDFS.jar

it is giving me class not found exception. Please suggest where I am wrong.

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.abc.Import.XMLHDFS.XML
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:278)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.classForName(Utils.scala:172)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.classForName(Utils.scala:172)
        ......................
```

Comment: Please add the error logs

Comment: Please find logs.

Comment: Have you checked the XMLHDFS.jar has the main class?

Comment: Just now I checked, It is not include any of my class or packages. I am not sure why it is not build in my jar. Any iDea?

Comment: Include your main class and dependencies in the jar and it will work fine.